# 32-bit multiplication without using a 64-bit intermediate number

Tags: c++, ieee-754

Is there any way to multiply two 32-bit floating point numbers without using a 64-bit intermediate value?

Background:
In an IEEE floating point number, 1-bit is devoted to the sign, 8-bits are devoted to the exponent, and 23-bits are devoted to the mantissa. When multiplying the two numbers, the mantissa's have to be multiplied separately. When doing this, you will end up with a 48-bit number (since the most significant bit of 1 is implied). After receiving a 48-bit number, that value should be truncated by 25-bits so that only the 23 most significant bits are retained in the result.

My question is that, to do this multiplication as is, you will need a 64-bit number to store the intermediate result. But, I'm assuming that there is a way to do this without using a 64-bit number since 32-bit architectures didn't have the luxury of using 64-bit numbers and they were still able to do 32-bit floating point number multiplication. So how can you do this without using a 64-bit intermediate number?

Comment: AFAIK, the internal processor's data type used for float manipulations in modern processors is even wider than 64 bit. So even on 32 bit architecture the internal types might have more bits.

Comment: unless you're on some embedded systems like 8-bit microcontrollers then there should already be some FPU which is capable of double-precision arithmetic. And if there's no FPU at all the there'll be software float from the compiler. No need to implement your own.

Answer (score 0):

From https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/newbie#floating-point-arith2 :

> floating point calculations and comparisons are often performed by
>   special hardware that often contain special registers, and those
>   registers often have more bits than a double.

So even on a 32bit architecture you probably have more-than-32-bits registers for floating point operations.